# RawInput - how to distinguish two identical mice

Tags: windows, winapi, raw-input

I have two questions regarding the RawAPI. I use it for sort of a game to distinguish between two mice (player1 and palyer2).

1. My implementation seems to work but if I connect two **identical** mice, even rawinput seems to see it as only one mouse. So I need to connect for example two mice from a different vendors or at least different models. Is there a way around this?
2. Can I somehow prevent the "secondary" mouse to control the mouse cursor? Either somewhere from Windows settings or directly from the RawInput of my app? I know there's nothing like primary or secondary mouse. What I mean is that I want to have only one mice moving the cursor and the rest to only be accessible via RawInput.

Comment: Sure that hDevice in the RAWINPUTHEADER is equal for both devices?

Comment: Raw Input distinquishes between different hardware devices. Attaching two identical mice SHOULD NOT be reporting events as a single mouse. If that is happening then you are likely not using the API correctly. Please show your actual code. As for preventing the second mouse from moving the cursor, Raw Input cant do that, you need a global mouse hook instead. Use Raw Input to identify when the second mouse is receiving input, and then have the mouse hook discard that input. It is not trivial to implement, though.

Comment: It might have been caused by a USB hub. I am not sure what changed but now it works. Also there seems to be two fake mice with some suspiciously low HANDLE values (it's not touchpad in case you wonder.. This is a desktop PC). And yes, I check it for RIM_TYPEMOUSE. I will investigate a bit more. In the meantime, any ideas for 2. ?

Comment: OK, seems I am checking whether it's mouse the wrong way. There are two ways I add mice to mice list. 1. At the beginning GetRawInputDeviceList() where it works fine, and 2. by catching WM_INPUT_DEVICE_CHANGE, which I don't do correctly because I don't check that for the device type. I don't know what those devices are, but it seems that's the source of the problems. I will have to call GetRawInputDeviceInfo to find out.

Comment: @user3095695 "*In the meantime, any ideas for 2. ?*" - I already addressed that in my previous comment. See [Combining Raw Input and keyboard Hook to selectively block input from multiple keyboards](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716591/Combining-Raw-Input-and-keyboard-Hook-to-selective), but using mouse input instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: No sorry didn't solve that one. I was only able to solve #1.